# Using an array of buttons in JFrame

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe, awt

I did a `JButton` array in Java, but I don't know to present them in the frame, is it possible?

This is the array, I inserted to each index `ImageIcon`:

```
JButton [] buttons=new JButton[55];
```

Comment: Well...how do you want to present them in the JFrame? What are the buttons for? It is most certainly possible.

Comment: I want to present them in blank  Jframe.

Comment: Obviously but in what format? Like in a grid similar to a calculator?

Comment: yes, for example.

Answer (score 2):

For example this:

```
javax.swing.JFrame frame = new javax.swing.JFrame("Just a JFrame Window Demo");
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

javax.swing.JPanel topPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
topPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout());
javax.swing.JLabel headerLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel(
        "50 JButtons in a grid using the GridLayout Layout:");
headerLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JLabel.CENTER);
headerLabel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 80));
topPanel.add(headerLabel);

javax.swing.JPanel centerPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
centerPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(5, 10));
javax.swing.JButton[] buttons = new javax.swing.JButton[50];
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i] = new javax.swing.JButton(String.valueOf(i));
    buttons[i].setName("button_" + i);
    buttons[i].addActionListener(new AllButtonsActionListener());
    centerPanel.add(buttons[i]);
}

javax.swing.JPanel bottomPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
bottomPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());
javax.swing.JButton somethingButton = new javax.swing.JButton("Some Button");
somethingButton.addActionListener(new AllButtonsActionListener());

javax.swing.JButton exitButton = new javax.swing.JButton("Exit");
exitButton.addActionListener(new AllButtonsActionListener());
bottomPanel.add(somethingButton);
bottomPanel.add(exitButton);

frame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame.pack();

javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
});
```

And an inner class to catch the button selection:

```
// Inner Class
class AllButtonsActionListener implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
        String aCmd = e.getActionCommand().toLowerCase();
        System.out.println("Action Command is: " + aCmd);

        if (aCmd.equals("exit")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

When the above code is run you should see...

[image]

When you select any button it's caption will be displayed in the console window.

Comment: Also resize the window when you get a chance :)

Comment: `somethingButton.setPreferredSize(..)` Better avoided. Change the size of a button by changing the text length or font size, the size of the icon or the margin.